# Something GZIPping and caching my JS & CSS files

Tags: javascript, css, caching, gzip

I'm using **SMARTY PHP TEMPLATE ENGINE** , **Apache 2** and **PHP 5.3.3** . This was my original main.js file content

```
// Functions
(function($){
    var url1 = /(^|&lt;|\s)(www\..+?\..+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g,
    url2 = /(^|&lt;|\s)(((https?|ftp):\/\/|mailto:).+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g,
    linkifyThis = function () {
        var childNodes = this.childNodes,
        i = childNodes.length;
        while(i--)
        {
            var n = childNodes[i];
            if (n.nodeType == 3) {
                var html = $.trim(n.nodeValue);
                if (html)
                {
                    html = html.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                    .replace(url1, '$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>$3')
                    .replace(url2, '$1<a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>$5');
                    $(n).after(html).remove();
                }
            }
            else if (n.nodeType == 1  &&  !/^(a|button|textarea)$/i.test(n.tagName)) {
                linkifyThis.call(n);
            }
        }
    };
    $.fn.linkify = function () {
        return this.each(linkifyThis);
    };
})(jQuery);

function openCenteredWindow(url, height, width, name, parms) {
   var left = Math.floor( (screen.width - width) / 2);
   var top = Math.floor( (screen.height - height) / 2);
   var winParms = "top=" + top + ",left=" + left + ",height=" + height + ",width=" + width;
   if (parms) { winParms += "," + parms; }
   var win = window.open(url, name, winParms);
   if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 4) { win.window.focus(); }
   return win;
}
```

But when i was browsing to my js file (*http://domain.com/js/main.js*) on browser, it's like this :

```
(function($){var url1=/(^|&lt;|\s)(www\..+?\..+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g,url2=/(^|&lt;|\s)(((https?|ftp):\/\/|mailto:).+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g,linkifyThis=function(){var childNodes=this.childNodes,i=childNodes.length;while(i--)
{var n=childNodes[i];if(n.nodeType==3){var html=$.trim(n.nodeValue);if(html)
{html=html.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;').replace(url1,'$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>$3').replace(url2,'$1<a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>$5');$(n).after(html).remove();}}
else if(n.nodeType==1&&!/^(a|button|textarea)$/i.test(n.tagName)){linkifyThis.call(n);}}};$.fn.linkify=function(){return this.each(linkifyThis);};})(jQuery);function openCenteredWindow(url,height,width,name,parms){var left=Math.floor((screen.width- width)/2);var top=Math.floor((screen.height- height)/2);var winParms="top="+ top+",left="+ left+",height="+ height+",width="+ width;if(parms){winParms+=","+ parms;}
var win=window.open(url,name,winParms);if(parseInt(navigator.appVersion)>=4){win.window.focus();}
return win;}
```

It's like GZIPPED, something removing newline characters and comment lines . Now i add something to *main.js* file. Now *main.js*'s original content is this :

```
// Functions
(function($){
    var url1 = /(^|&lt;|\s)(www\..+?\..+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g,
    url2 = /(^|&lt;|\s)(((https?|ftp):\/\/|mailto:).+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g,
    linkifyThis = function () {
        var childNodes = this.childNodes,
        i = childNodes.length;
        while(i--)
        {
            var n = childNodes[i];
            if (n.nodeType == 3) {
                var html = $.trim(n.nodeValue);
                if (html)
                {
                    html = html.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                    .replace(url1, '$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>$3')
                    .replace(url2, '$1<a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>$5');
                    $(n).after(html).remove();
                }
            }
            else if (n.nodeType == 1  &&  !/^(a|button|textarea)$/i.test(n.tagName)) {
                linkifyThis.call(n);
            }
        }
    };
    $.fn.linkify = function () {
        return this.each(linkifyThis);
    };
})(jQuery);

function openCenteredWindow(url, height, width, name, parms) {
   var left = Math.floor( (screen.width - width) / 2);
   var top = Math.floor( (screen.height - height) / 2);
   var winParms = "top=" + top + ",left=" + left + ",height=" + height + ",width=" + width;
   if (parms) { winParms += "," + parms; }
   var win = window.open(url, name, winParms);
   if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 4) { win.window.focus(); }
   return win;
}

$(document).ready({

    /*

    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;

    */

    /*  dropdown sub-menu control
    ***************************/

    var leftItemSub = $('.loginbarLeftItem').find('ul');
    var rightItemSub = $('.loginbarRightItem').find('ul');
    if(leftItemSub.length){
        leftItemSub.parent().css({
            '-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius': '10px !important',
            '-moz-border-radius-bottomleft': '10px !important',
            'border-bottom-left-radius': '10px !important'
        });
    }
    if(rightItemSub.length){
        rightItemSub.parent().css({
            '-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius': '10px !important',
            '-moz-border-radius-bottomleft': '10px !important',
            'border-bottom-left-radius': '10px !important'
        });
    }
});
```

But when i browse to my *main.js* file on browser, it's same (there aren't new lines and there aren't newly added content)

```
(function($){var url1=/(^|&lt;|\s)(www\..+?\..+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g,url2=/(^|&lt;|\s)(((https?|ftp):\/\/|mailto:).+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g,linkifyThis=function(){var childNodes=this.childNodes,i=childNodes.length;while(i--)
{var n=childNodes[i];if(n.nodeType==3){var html=$.trim(n.nodeValue);if(html)
{html=html.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;').replace(url1,'$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>$3').replace(url2,'$1<a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>$5');$(n).after(html).remove();}}
else if(n.nodeType==1&&!/^(a|button|textarea)$/i.test(n.tagName)){linkifyThis.call(n);}}};$.fn.linkify=function(){return this.each(linkifyThis);};})(jQuery);function openCenteredWindow(url,height,width,name,parms){var left=Math.floor((screen.width- width)/2);var top=Math.floor((screen.height- height)/2);var winParms="top="+ top+",left="+ left+",height="+ height+",width="+ width;if(parms){winParms+=","+ parms;}
var win=window.open(url,name,winParms);if(parseInt(navigator.appVersion)>=4){win.window.focus();}
return win;}
```

Same problem for CSS files. Something GZIPing and caching my JS and CSS files. But i couldn't find it. I've tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

Any ideas ?

**NOTE 1**

there isn't **.htaccess** file on /js and /css folders . But there is a .htaccess on root folder.

```
options -multiviews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^users$ users.php
RewriteRule ^categories/([^/.]+)?$ cat.php?cid=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^user/([^/.]+)?$ user.php?uname=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)?$ tags.php?cid=$1&tag=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]*)?$ view.php?title=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c> 
   # Turn off mod_security filtering. 
   SecFilterEngine Off 

   # The below probably isn't needed, 
   # but better safe than sorry. 
   SecFilterScanPOST Off 
</IfModule>
```

**Note 2**

when i browse to `main.js?(randomnumbers)` (`like main.js?345458`) i can see fresh version . But still there isn't comment lines and new lines.

Comment: You are probably using a framework to build your site, please add that to your question, and also include on what type of hosting you are, Apache?

Comment: @SimonGroenewolt , i'm not using a framework. BUt i'm using **Smarty** . Also i'm using **Apache** . (i added them to my question)

Comment: Please look for a `.htaccess` file in your `/js` or `/` folder. Note that it might be hidden by default, so you need to tell your file GUI to show hiddenfiles. Post the content, if any.

Comment: @pixelistik please check NOTE1

Comment: That's not gzipped. That's just whitespace-trimmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed, CloudFlare is activated for my domain. And CloudFlare *caching / GZIPping* my *js / css* files automatically. I deactivate it and solved my problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that something like https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/mod is installed on the webserver.

What happens when you request: http://domain.com/js/main.js?cachebuster=somethingrandom to (hopefully) force a really fresh version of main.js?

Update: Reading in the comments that changing the url parameters will give you a fresh version it could very well be a proxy somewhere, either on your own server or somewhere else.

Comment: i couldn't see it on my **phpinfo()** , i mean it's not installed. Actually it's a fresh Centos installation.

Comment: added: What happens when you request: http://domain.com/js/main.js?cachebuster=somethingrandom to (hopefully) force a really fresh version of main.js?

Comment: when i browse to `main.js?(randomnumbers)` i can see fresh version . But still there isn't comment lines and new lines.

Comment: Ok so that definitely points toward something that is compressing your files and storing the result - either an apache module or something that is between you and your server (A proxy perhaps? That would explain why a browser refresh didn't work).

Comment: it can be CloudFLare ? I'll disable it and try again

Comment: @Enray did disabling CloudFlare fix your issues?